# Tesseract: Certainty scores for each character

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to figure out how I can get all confidence values that are calculated by Tesseract for every character. The same approach is described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/tesseract-ocr/Ac25kEXHfQQ):

```
a(0.01)..b(0.02)....n(0.6) ..    ..z(0.01)  --> recognized as 'n'
a(0.01)..b(0.02)....o(0.7)   ..  ..z(0.01)  --> recognized as 'o'
```

However, not being very familiar with C++, I fail to map this to the current source code.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the confidence value by using `ResultIterator::Confidence()`. Look at this [example](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Result_iterator_example) and replace `tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;` with 
`tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_SYMBOL;` to get the confidence value for each character.

You can use more levels, just look [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/ccstruct/publictypes.h#204).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think I didn't make clear what confidence values I'm looking for. I added an example to the original posting.